# Can't Get Request Parameters in Jax-Rs Java

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a web service using jax-rs, java and IntelliJ IDEA. I implemented it as below:

```
@POST
@Path("/register")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response registerUSer(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    JSONObject data = UserRegitrationProvider.registerUser(request);

    return Response.ok().entity(data.toString()).build();
}
```

Provider:

```
public static JSONObject registerUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    UserRegistrationRepository userRegistrationRepository = new UserRegistrationRepository();
    HashMap<String, String> userInformations = new HashMap<>();

    String username = request.getHeader("username");
    String password = request.getHeader("password");
    String userID = request.getHeader("userid");
    String userType = request.getHeader("usertype");

    System.out.println(username + " - " + userID + " - " + userType + " - " + password);

    userInformations.put("username", username);
    userInformations.put("password", password);
    userInformations.put("userid", userID);
    userInformations.put("usertype", userType);

    userRegistrationRepository.saveUserInfo(userInformations);

    result.put("status", 200);
    return result;
}
```

I am using REST Client plugin in IntelliJ to send a post request to my rest API. In here I send username, password ... as request parameters.
In the provider class, at the request.getHeader() part I can not get the username or any other data. I am adding these parameters to request parameters part of the REST client.

I also tried getAttribute() and getParameter() methods of the request but they did not return anything as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be confusing headers with request params (title says request params, code says headers). Can you please show the request e.g. exported as `curl` command?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Actually I said that I tryed both headers and parameters in my question. Here is my request.xml file: http://www.pubtekno.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/request.xml Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I could take a look if you convert your request to `curl` syntax. I don't have the IntelliJ REST Client (is it only ultimate version?).

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I actually do not know th curl syntax. IntelliJ REST Client is placed under the Tools tab on the top menu. What do you need to know about the request? I sent username, password .. other as parameter and you can see these in the request.xml file that I shared above. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the example of your request.